# How to use the enable Pin and Error Flag Pin of MIC29301 12V regulator with an Arduino

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, digital-logic, voltage-regulator, ldo

I am completely new to electronics and I am looking to implement a simple 12V Vacuum Pump power and control circuit with an Arduino.

I chose the MIC29301 as the 12Vout regulator to be directly connected with a 12V lifePo 4 battery. The diagram is attached below:

[image: 12V regulator]

The GND, IN, and Out were pretty straightforward. However, I am trying to be careful with the Enable and Flag pins as I don't know a lot about them.

My question is how do I connect the enable pins with an Arduino to use it as an on/off logic switch (i.e if resistors are required or it can be connected directly)

My other question is about the Error Flag pin which I am completely new to. I am trying to use this pin to read for drop in output voltage from the regulator, but I am completely lost on how to use this pin or connect it with the Arduino. Please I would love some guidance and explanations on how and why some of the recommendations will work. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the MIC29301 datasheet?  There is a lot of information there including typical application circuits.

Comment: Yes, I did, and while there is a lot of information, there is barely any useful one on the flag pins and enable pins, at least for my level of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always refer to datasheets for the information you are looking for.

**From the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC2915x-30x-50x-75x-High-Current-Low-Dropout-Regulators-DS20005685B.pdf):**

> On the MIC29xx1 and MIC29xx2, the ENABLE pin may
> be tied to VIN if it is not required for ON/OFF control.

> CMOS compatible control input. Logic-high =
> enable, logic-low = shutdown.

> MIC29xx1 and MIC29xx2 versions feature an enable
> (EN) input that allows ON/OFF control of the device. The EN input has TTL/CMOS compatible
> thresholds for simple interfacing with logic, or may be
> directly tied to ≤30V

So, you can control the ENABLE pin using digital output of Arduino directly.

**Also from the datasheet:**

> Active-low error flag output signal that indicates an
> output fault condition.

> Error
> Flag, which looks at the output voltage and signals an
> error condition when this voltage drops 5% below its
> expected value. The error flag is an open-collector
> output that pulls low under fault conditions. It may sink
> 10 mA.

Since FLAG is an open collector output, you have to put an appropriate pull-up resistor. You can then read the FLAG pin using digital input of Arduino.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I stated, I am new to this and datasheets still takes time to get used to. As per your advice on the flag pin, do you mean I put an appropriate pull-up resistor to the digital pin of the Arduino, or to the output pin of the regulator?

Comment: Both are the same thing. You connect output flag pin to the input of Arduino. Put pull-up on this connection.

Comment: Kindly accept an answer as solution if it solved your problem, so that it helps others in future.

Comment: I just accepted it as the answer, sorry I am new to the Stackexchange system. Also, please for the pull-up resistor, is there anything, in particular, I should be taking into consideration with regards to the resistor value?

Comment: Yes, as said in the datasheet, the resistor should limit the sinking current to 10 mA.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks a lot